# mysql: 1 INSERT INTO query two result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table user (id VARCHAR(5), name VARCHAR(30))

I used INSERT INTO query in two way:

1) Directly:

```
...
$sql="INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES ('00001','abcd');
...
```

---> result: `id(00001), name(abcd).`

That's the right result.

2) By function:

```
function insert($id,$name)
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES ($id,$name)";
    ....
}
```

I used this function with 2 kind of parameter
a)

```
insert('00001','00123');
```

---> result: `id(1), name(123)` (all zeros have been cut).

b)

```
insert('00001','abcd');
```

---> error: `Unknown column 'abcd' in 'field list'.`

I want to ask: why all the zeros have been cut, and why when I used a string value it make an error. How can I fix it to get right result by function.
Many thanks!

Comment: Besides the problem at hand.. Why would you want to use a varchar as ID colum? Why not just use integer, autoincrement? Then you also won;t have to worry about duplicates.

Comment: you have to use single quote (') on your query...
$sql="INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES ('$id', '$name')";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never bothered quoting your values:

```
INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES ($id,$name)
                                   ^^^^^^^^^---here
```

So the query becomes

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1, abcd)
```

Without the quotes, `abcd` is seen as a FIELD NAME, not a value. Since your table has no field named `abcd`, you get your error. Try:

```
INSERT INTO user (id,name) VALUES ($id, '$name')
```

as a short-term fix (note the `'` quotes around `$name`). Long term fix: Start using prepared statements and/or placeholders, which eliminate the need for this kind of quoting.

Comment: "Edits must be 6 characters"...well that's dumb.  To fix the leading-zero stripping problem, put quotes around $id as well.

Comment: very silly using zero padding and non-int id fields anyways. The padding can be EASILY be reapplied when querying the data for display anyways.

Comment: Agreed, but we don't know the OP's requirements.  Perhaps someone else insisted that the ID field be a string.